# How to use different UI like <p:dialog> in the error message which is shown on filesize exceeded error message in prime faces?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am checking file size when files are uploaded in JSF primefaces. I am using `<p:fileUpload>` tag for file upload and for restricting file size I am using sizeLimit. Everything works fine but I want to use a different ui component like dialog box (`<p:dialog>` tag) instead the default UI which shows error message with file name,file size and error message.

Comment: did you tchek about growl message or simplly a dialog message ?!?

Comment: using an AjaxStatus to work every time you click ?!?

Answer (score 0):

It don't seems that fileUpload component has another way to show this message natively. Your best shot is to Modify the **showMessage** method of the javascript variable that is created to represent the component.

Use the **widgetVar** attribute like this

```
<p:fileUpload ... widgetVar="myfupload">
```

And then you replace the **showMessage** method (function) of this variable this way

```
<script>
    myfupload.showMessage = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.summary);
    }
</script>
```

Of couse the better and safest way to achieve this is to extend the PrimeFaces component, but, this is the fastest way to try what you want to do.

Cheers

Comment: This is not working, its still showing default message with file name, file size and message as invalid file size.